# INSTALLING SQL SERVER 2008 in Windows XP

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-xp, .net-4.5

Hello this is my first time in Server Fault so I wish people are as accommodating here as in Stack Overflow.

So.. Heres the thing. I need to install SQL Server 2008 Express 32 Bit on a Windows XP environment.

I have already downloaded the installers but when i tried to run the setup it prompt that it needed a .net framework 4.5 installed in the pc.

Here is the exact error message:

> Blocking Issues: The .Net Framework 4.5 is not supported on this
>   operating system.

Which is weird since I have seen tutorials on installing SQL Server 2008 in XP.

Anyone please push me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Ok so I forgot to mention that I need MS Sql Management studio as well...i always thinks this is pre bundled so i didnt note it out. Anyway the accepted answer led me to this link

[MS SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO DOWNLOAD](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Thanks Mark :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no .NET 4.5 requirement for SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2008 pre-dates .NET 4.5 by quite a few years. Additionally, I have many SQL Server 2008 R2 installations that do not have this requirement.

I suspect you are not actually installing SQL Server 2008. Where did you get the installers from? What was their download links? The correct download link is: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=1695 - as you can see it was published in 2009, which predates .NET 4.5

Comment: I got the installer from our repository so im not really sure which site it came from. Thank you for providing the link. Will download and will get back on you this. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning it in my comment. But the download link does not include ms sql management studio 2008? i always think both applications are the same. I apologize.

Comment: The link to SSMS was on the previous page as well, under the related downloads: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need an earlier version of the software.  Recent updates have likely added support for `.NET 4.5`, which you will not be able to use.  Unfortunately, Microsoft may not provide a download for you.

Comment: That download link is tagged to work with XP: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30438 , but it's SQL Server 2008 R2, but it state it need dotnet 2.0

Comment: Try installing [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=26729) first and then just applying the patch for SP2.  MSSQL installers are notoriously bad at documenting or handling any kind of unexpected condition.